# Perform inner join using python and re-order original columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two datasets, df1 and df2, where:

I would like to perform an 'inner-join' on the **date** and **name** columns
however, I wish to re-order some of the columns as well.

df1

```
name    freeG   totalG  sku      date
a       4       10      hi       10/10/2020
b       10      20      hi       10/10/2020
c       8       10      hello    10/10/2020
d       1       5       hello    10/10/2020
e       1       5       hey      10/10/2020
f       2       5       hey      10/10/2020
g       1       5       hey      10/10/2020
```

df2

```
total   freeS   usedS   name   date  
10      5       5       a      10/10/2020
20      10      10      b      10/10/2020
30      5       25      c      10/10/2020
40      10      30      d      10/10/2020
50      10      40      e      10/10/2020
10      5       5       f      10/10/2020
10      5       5       g      10/10/2020
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
date           name freeG   totalG  sku     usedS   freeS   total  
10/10/2020      a   4       10      hi      5       5       10
10/10/2020      b   10      20      hi      10      10      20
10/10/2020      c   8       10      hello   25      5       30
10/10/2020      d   1       5       hello   30      10      40
10/10/2020      e   1       5       hey     40      10      50
10/10/2020      f   2       5       hey     5       5       10
10/10/2020      g   1       5       hey     5       5       10
```

**This is what I am doing**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


new = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner', inner_on=['date','name'])
```

//change order of columns

```
new1 = new[['date', 'name', 'freeG', 'totalG', 'sku', 'usedS', 'freeS', 'total']]
```

However, I am not able to join using the above syntax. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: " I am not able to join using the above syntax" please describe what is wrong with your current attempt. Is the output wrong? Is there an error? Detail will help us know how to help you better

Comment: sure - inner_on =  syntax is not correct. I am researching this now

Comment: Rather than using concat if you want to join, why not just use [dataframe.join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)?

Comment: ok thank you @G.Anderson - I will try this - The documentation has only one column place to join on I believe. Could I add more than one?

Comment: Also helpful: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner',on=['name', 'date'])#merge
new['total']=new.freeS.add(new.usedS)#compute  total

new1 = new[['date', 'name', 'freeG', 'totalG', 'sku', 'usedS', 'freeS', 'total']]   # align columns
new1
```

Comment: This works thank you @wwnde - I was not sure of the correct syntax to use when joining. I was using 'inner_on' . Thank you

Comment: Oh Hi @Wwnde now I am getting this error: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
 - maybe I need double quotes? its pointing to  this part: on=['name', 'date'])

Comment: I figured it out- I removed the brackets. I was only joining on one column just now. I did: join= pd.merge(df1, df2 how='inner', on= 'Name')    - perhaps when you join on more than one column you use []? thank you